# Dynamically expanding shapes

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I made a rounded rectangle in as3 and would like to expand it on click. This is the code I use:

```
var lesBg:Sprite = new Sprite();
with (lesBg.graphics) {
    lineStyle(3, 0x61b157);
    beginFill(0xececec);
    drawRoundRect(0,0,190,52*les.duur, 10,10);
    endFill();
}
currentPanel.addChild(lesBg);
```

When I click on it I would like it to expand to twice its size. I'm doing this with TweenLite but when I expand it I get ugly pixelated images and the borders expand too.

```
Tweenlite.to(lesBg, 1,{width: 380});
```

Is it possible to expand the image so it stays clean and the borders stay intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 9-slice option for you movieclip.

You can find more about it here: http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/scale9/

Answer (score 0):

OR you could redraw your rectangle while tweening a dummy object like this.

```
var obj:Object = {width: 100};
TweenLite.to( obj, 1, {width: 380, onUpdate:update} );

function update():void {
  var g:Graphics = lesBg.graphics;
  g.drawRoundRect( 0, 0, obj.width, 52*les.duur, 10, 10 );
}
```